# Disable list box selected item color

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am using istBox and I want to disable the color of it when you
selected item(by default its blue )I was tried like this
but when you select item you dont see it...,any idea how to disable the color /

```
<ListBox.Resources>
            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="Transparent" />


        </ListBox.Resources>
```

**UPDATE**

```
            x:Name="LstUsers" Height="115" Width="150" 

            ItemsSource="{Binding UsersCollectionView}" 
                 AllowDrop="True" 
                  PreviewKeyDown="ListBoxPreviewKeyDown"  
                 PreviewDrop="ListBox_PreviewDrop"
                 PreviewMouseDown="listBox_PreviewMouseMove"
                 Margin="45,119,805,445"
                 MouseUp="listBox_MouseUp"
                 PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"


                  Drop="ListBox_Drop">


        </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ItemsControl` instead of `ListBox`.

It doesn't have all those fancy templates you have for ListBox (including no highlight color).

---

Like you mentioned in comment that you want `SelectionChanged` event which unfortunately is `not in ItemsControl`. Only other way to disable Selection highlight color is to ***override Template of ListBoxItem***. This is how you do it:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                   <ContentPresenter
                       Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                       ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                       ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks ,currently I use the with the list box the following code ,how should i change it if i use item control   UserList.Remove(LstUsers.SelectedItem as User);

Comment: Just replace `ListBox` with `ItemsControl` that's it. No need to override HighlightBrush in that case since it's already transparent by default. ItemsControl is base class of ListBox without any fancy templates like i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: D&D events can be done on ItemsControl as well since it's base class of ListBox. Have you tried it?

Comment: but now when I change it the D&D events not working..and I dont able to remove the item as beefore

Comment: We need to see the code which is not working otherwise it will be all just words in air.

Comment: Forget to update the code in the class,just one thing how sholud  I write this in item control listBox.SelectedItem

Comment: But i guess you don't want selection in your ListBox. Isn't it?

Comment: Please check the update in answer. See if that helps.

Comment: Nop,actually I D&D from the list box but I'll open diffrent question about this issue ,thanks anyway